# I can't insert into SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

My code below:

```
public void InsertarClienteBD(int intCedula, string strNombre, string strApellido, string strTelefono, string strDireccion)
{
    SqlConnection cnnConexion = ObtenerConexion();
    string strSentenciaSQL = "insert into Clientes (cedula, nombre, apellido, telefono, direccion) values ({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}) ";
   strSentenciaSQL = string.Format(strSentenciaSQL, intCedula, strNombre, strApellido, strTelefono, strDireccion);
    SqlCommand cmdComando = new SqlCommand(strSentenciaSQL, cnnConexion); 
    cmdComando.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cnnConexion.Close();
}
```

I got below error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException' occurred in
>   System.Web.Services.dll
>
> Additional information: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Your code doesn't mention `SOAP`(Simple Object Access Protocol) at all, are you using SOAP somewhere else? Or is it using SOAP to connect to SQL?? You are getting SOAP Exceptions

Comment: Thanks, 3 hour loss of my life, now work...

Answer (score 1):

First I would check the values that you are passing to see if they are the proper data type for each field.

Second I would look at using parameters with your query as marc_s suggested. That would clear up any data type issue you may be having. For example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.100).aspx